# Does there exists another approach to solve for the product of such expression?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, solution-verification

Problem: if the real roots of $x^3-3x+1$ are $\alpha , \beta $ and $\gamma,$ then what is the value of cyclic $(\alpha^2-\gamma)\;?$

Here is my approach, using trigonometry. Is my work correct?

[image]

Comment: Vieta’s formulae strike me as simpler

Comment: I tried can you check ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax The value of the expression depends on the choice of roots. It is indeed $\,8\,$ with your choice, but it's a [different](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+%28a%5E2+-+c%29%28b%5E2+-+a%29%28c%5E2+-+b%29++where+b+%3D+2+cos%288+pi%2F9%29%2C++a+%3D+2+cos%284+pi%2F9%29%2C++c+%3D+2+cos%282+pi%2F9%29) value if you swap $\,\alpha,\beta\,$ for example.

Comment: Yes @dxiv just in that order we have to find the value , i intially tried vieta only

Comment: @Orion_Pax The cyclic product $\,\prod_{cyc} (\alpha^2 - \gamma)\,$ is not symmetric in $\,\alpha, \beta, \gamma\,$, so you won't be able to use Vieta's alone to calculate it. You could use Vieta's to calculate the (symmetric) product of the *six* terms $\,\prod (\alpha^2 - \gamma)(\alpha^2 - \beta)\,$, but then you'd still have to extract the subproduct of the three cyclic terms from it. That part is not trivial, and would require computations equivalent to the solution using resultants.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be brute-forced algebraically, but the calculations involve polynomial [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) and are laborious to do by hand, though easily computed using a CAS.

Let $\,x_1=\alpha, x_2=\beta, x_3=\gamma\,$, then the polynomial in $\,y\,$ with roots $\,x_i^2\,$ [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E3-3x%2B1%2C+y-x%5E2%2C+x%29):

$$\text{res}(x^3-3x+1, y-x^2, x)=y^3 - 6 y^2 + 9 y - 1 \tag{1}$$

The polynomial in $\,z,y\,$ with roots $\,x_i^2-x_j = y_i-x_j\,$ [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E3-3x%2B1%2C+z-y%2Bx%2C+x%29) :

$$
\text{res}(x^3-3x+1, z-y+x, x) = -y^3 + 3 y^2 z - 3 y z^2 + 3 y + z^3 - 3 z - 1 \tag{2}
$$

Then, the polynomial in $\,z\,$ alone is found by eliminating $\,y\,$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$, which [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28y%5E3+-+6+y%5E2+%2B+9+y+-+1%2C+-y%5E3+%2B+3+y%5E2+z+-+3+y+z%5E2+%2B+3+y+%2B+z%5E3+-+3+z+-+1%2C+y%29):

$$
\begin{align}
& \text{res}(y^3 - 6 y^2 + 9 y - 1, -y^3 + 3 y^2 z - 3 y z^2 + 3 y + z^3 - 3 z - 1, y)
\\ =\, &(z - 2)^3 (z^3 - 6 z^2 + 3 z + 19) (z^3 - 6 z^2 + 3 z + 1) \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Three of the $\,z\,$ roots are $\,x_i^2-x_i\,$, which are the roots of:

$$
\text{res}(x^3-3x+1, z-x^2+x, x) = z^3 - 6 z^2 + 3 z + 1 \tag{4}
$$

This corresponds to the last factor in $\,(3)\,$, which leaves the two possibilities $(\dagger)\,$:

- $(z-2)^3 = 0\,$ with the triple root $\,2\,$ so $\,z_1z_2z_3=8\,$, which is OP's solution;
- $z^3 - 6 z^2 + 3 z + 19\,$ with the product of the roots $\,z_1z_2z_3=-19\,$, which is the second solution linked in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394493/does-there-exists-another-approach-to-solve-for-the-product-of-such-expression#comment9192736_4394493).

$(\dagger)\;$ The relevant sextic in $\,(3)\,$ can be factored into two cubics in $\,\binom{6}{3}\,$ ways, but we know that $\,(x_1^2-x_2)+(x_2^2-x_3)+(x_3^2-x_1)=6\,$ and the only factorization where the coefficient of $\,x^2\,$ is $\,-6\,$ in a cubic factor is where the factors are chosen to be $\,(z-2)^3\,$ and $\,z^3 - 6 z^2 + 3 z + 19\,$.